# Java.lang.AbstractMethodError in spring data Cassandra 1.5.x version with spring framework 4.3.x version

Tags: spring, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

While trying to connect to Apache Cassandra 3.0 version with spring data Cassandra facing following error.. running this in Java 1.7. also using datastax Cassandra driver core 3.0.1. 
Seems like isAnnotationPresent(annotationType) method implementation is missing in org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraParameters$AnnotatedParameter class, causing this error. Can someone pls help resolving this.

Java.lang.AbstractMethodError
At org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementsUtils.java:617)
At org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraParameters$CassandraParameter.(CassandraParameters.java:83)

Comment: please add the snippet of code that causes this...

Comment: I got the issue, it was due to java 1.7, seems like spring data Cassandra 1.5.x built using java 1.8. there was a default implementation for isAnnotationPresent method in AnnotatedElement interface with jdk 1.8. so when used spring data Cassandra 1.5.x with jdk 1.8, this error is gone.